# Create object with properties and values from another object using ES6 object destructuring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm constantly confused whether object destructuring in javascript applies in certain situations, and I've just come across one. In this code I am simply taking properties from the `this` object and assigning them to the same property/value on a new `data` object:

```
const data = {
    rating: this.rating,
    title: this.title,
    text: this.text,
    name: this.name,
    location: this.location,
    email: this.email,
    files: this.files
};
```

Can some sort of object destructuring be used to accomplish this instead or is it unrelated to this use-case?

Comment: Did you want ALL properties or selected ones

Comment: @JaromandaX Just the selected ones I show in the example.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the spread operator if you want all the own properties of `this`:

```
const data = {
  ...this
}
```

If you only need a selective few, you can delete the unnecessary properties afterwards, or set them to undefined (although that's different from non-existent/deleted properties):

```
const data = {
  ...this,
  unwantedProp: undefined,
}
```

Comment: That's not destructuring, that's only spread syntax use.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this

```
const choose = (src, ...keys) => keys.reduce((result, key) => ({ ...result, [key]: src[key] }), {});
```

example usage

```js
const choose = (src, ...keys) => keys.reduce((result, key) => ({ ...result, [key]: src[key] }), {});


const src = {
    rating: 1,
    title: 2,
    text: 3,
    name: 4,
    location: 5,
    email: 6,
    files: 7,
    not_me: 8
};

const data = choose(src, 'rating', 'title', 'text', 'name', 'location', 'email', 'files');
console.log(data);
```

In your case, you'd use `this` instead of `src` when calling choose

Comment: Very cool solution. Though I was more curious if there was a simple way to do this inline with destructuring. I was not looking to create a new function like you have with `choose`. Seems like the answer may just be "no".

Comment: No, can't think of anything without creating a function